# When credentials are autocompleted the input becomes yellow and goes over the border

Tags: react-native, expo

When I autocomplete stored credentials for the login form everything is getting pasted nicely, however the background becomes yellow (which wouldnt be horrible), but it goes over the rounded corners of the input.
Is it possible to contain it within the input styling or turning it off completely without using the ability to autocomplete?

I assume I would have more options if I ejected from expo but I don't want to do that.

Here's the code:

```
        <TextInput
                {...props}
                autoCapitalize="none"
                style={inputStyles}
                placeholderTextColor={dark}
                value={field.value}
                onChangeText={field.onChange}
                secureTextEntry={!!hideText}
            />
```

styling:

```
input: {
textAlignVertical: "center",
height: '100%',
paddingHorizontal: hp('3%'),
fontSize: hp('1.8%'),
backgroundColor: gray,
color: black,
borderRadius: hp('5%'),
width: '100%',
fontFamily: 'poppins-light',
borderWidth: 3
```

},

And this is how it looks:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7OO5.png

[image]